# How to find flights leaving an airport on a specific date?

Tags: bookings, flight-search-engines

How can you find all flights leaving an airport on a specific date?
The date may be more than a month ahead.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting this? It sounds a lot like you're having some kind of X-Y problem.

Comment: The reason is I want to plan a weekend trip but I'm not sure about the destination (get inspired by offers) and want to see all flights leaving the airport on a specific Friday.

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica suppose you're looking for a holiday from a certain date and want to know where you can get to directly (no stopovers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered that [Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights) offers exactly what I was looking for.

For example, if you plug-in VIE airport and don't enter a destination but your desired dates (e.g. Fr-Mo for a weekend trip) then GF is suggesting you destinations:

[image]

When you click on the map saying "Explore destinations" you will see all destinations with prices for your dates. You can even filter on nonstop flights, on prices, and a time range for departure/arrival:
[image]

Plus, booking the flights is a few clicks away.

Answer (score 4):

Skyscanner will allow you to search for flights to "Everywhere" for a specific date, and airport, it gives a list of destination countries.

If the date isn't to far in advance, then you could search for the date on flightradar24; or search for the same-day-of-the-week, last week.

Answer (score 2):

A subscription tool like [ExpertFlyer](http://www.expertflyer.com) can grab a list of all flights presently scheduled to leave or arrive at a certain airport on a certain day. (I expect its competitor KVS can do the same thing.)

Unlike SkyScanner or a booking website, which will require seats to be available, this simply shows the flights that are scheduled.

Also, there are rudimentary tools for sifting the results by airline, airport, *et c.*, and the data are easily exported to Excel for a more thorough analysis.

*e.g.*, looking at departures from BEY (Beirut) on the 1st of December this year:

```
Flight Timetables Search:
Search From BEY on 01/12/17 

Flight         Stops   Depart            Arrive            Aircraft     Duration         Frequency        Effective        Ending
ME 3310        0       BEY 0:10          AMM 2:00          E95          1 hr 50 mins     F                01/12/17         01/12/17

ME 4436        0       BEY 0:45          DOH 5:55          320          4 hrs 10 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

QR 419         0       BEY 0:45          DOH 5:55          320          4 hrs 10 mins    Daily            26/11/17         24/03/18

EK 956         0       BEY 1:05          DXB 6:55          77W          3 hrs 50 mins    Daily            28/11/17         24/03/18

AF (ME) 5105   0       BEY 2:05          CDG 5:45          332          4 hrs 40 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

OK 3364        0       BEY 2:05          CDG 5:45          332          4 hrs 40 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 209         0       BEY 2:05          CDG 5:45          332          4 hrs 40 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 571         0       BEY 2:05          LOS 8:05          332          7 hrs 0 mins     T,F              05/11/17         05/01/18

ET 407         0       BEY 2:35          ADD 8:00          763          4 hrs 25 mins    W,F              29/11/17         01/12/17

ME 2829        0       BEY 2:55          IST 5:55          333          2 hrs 0 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

TK 829         0       BEY 2:55          IST 5:55          332          2 hrs 0 mins     F,Sa             25/11/17         08/12/17

GM 8757        0       BEY 3:05          ZRH 6:30          319          4 hrs 25 mins    M,F              05/11/17         26/03/18

PC 758         0       BEY 3:45          SAW 6:40          738          1 hr 55 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 2255        0       BEY 3:50          OTP 6:15          73W          2 hrs 25 mins    W,F,Su           05/11/17         23/03/18

RO 168         0       BEY 3:50          OTP 6:15          733          2 hrs 25 mins    W,F,Su           05/11/17         23/03/18

A3 937         0       BEY 4:15          ATH 6:15          320          2 hrs 0 mins     F                01/12/17         15/12/17

AZ 827         0       BEY 4:25          FCO 7:00          32S          3 hrs 35 mins    T,Th,F,Sa        14/11/17         24/03/18

ME 2233        0       BEY 4:25          FCO 7:00          32S          3 hrs 35 mins    T,Th,F,Sa        05/11/17         24/03/18

PC 863         0       BEY 4:45          SAW 7:40          738          1 hr 55 mins     Daily            05/11/17         14/01/18

MS 714         0       BEY 5:00          CAI 6:25          738          1 hr 25 mins     Th,F,Sa          30/11/17         08/12/17

LH 1307        0       BEY 5:15          FRA 8:40          321          4 hrs 25 mins    M,T,W,Th,F,Sa    25/11/17         02/12/17

KK 1335        0       BEY 5:40          IST 8:40          321          2 hrs 0 mins     T,F              28/11/17         01/12/17

IA 3356        0       BEY 6:00          NJF 8:30          330          1 hr 30 mins     F                17/11/17         18/11/18

ME 4432        0       BEY 6:25          DOH 11:35         320          4 hrs 10 mins    Daily            05/11/17         18/12/17

QR 427         0       BEY 6:25          DOH 11:35         320          4 hrs 10 mins    Daily            21/11/17         18/12/17

IA 3366        0       BEY 6:30          NJF 9:00          321          1 hr 30 mins     F                17/11/17         18/11/18

ME 2827        0       BEY 6:35          IST 9:35          321          2 hrs 0 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

TK 827         0       BEY 6:35          IST 9:35          321          2 hrs 0 mins     Daily            21/11/17         15/12/17

ME 217         0       BEY 7:15          FRA 10:40         320          4 hrs 25 mins    M,T,W,Th,F,Su    05/11/17         19/12/17

ME 426         0       BEY 7:20          DXB 12:30         320          3 hrs 10 mins    Daily            01/12/17         14/12/17

ME 213         0       BEY 7:25          GVA 10:40         320          4 hrs 15 mins    M,W,Th,F,Sa,Su   30/11/17         06/12/17

ME 201         0       BEY 7:35          LHR 10:45         320          5 hrs 10 mins    M,T,Th,F,Sa      05/11/17         18/12/17

AF (ME) 5107   0       BEY 7:50          CDG 11:35         332          4 hrs 45 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

OK 3366        0       BEY 7:50          CDG 11:35         332          4 hrs 45 mins    M,W,Th,F,Sa,Su   05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 211         0       BEY 7:50          CDG 11:35         332          4 hrs 45 mins    M,W,Th,F,Sa,Su   05/11/17         24/03/18

CO 441         0       BEY 8:00          LCA 8:45          320           45 mins         M,F,Sa           27/11/17         27/01/18

AZ (ME) 7255   0       BEY 8:05          MXP 11:05         320          4 hrs 0 mins     M,W,F,Sa         05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 235         0       BEY 8:05          MXP 11:05         320          4 hrs 0 mins     M,W,F,Sa         05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 310         0       BEY 8:10          AMM 9:20          320          1 hr 10 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

RJ (ME) 3751   0       BEY 8:10          AMM 9:20          320          1 hr 10 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 251         0       BEY 8:15          ATH 10:15         320          2 hrs 0 mins     T,Th,F           05/11/17         23/03/18

ME 265         0       BEY 8:25          IST 11:20         332          1 hr 55 mins     Daily            21/11/17         14/12/17

TK (ME) 8165   0       BEY 8:25          IST 11:20         332          1 hr 55 mins     Daily            21/11/17         14/12/17

ME 424         0       BEY 8:25          RUH 11:40         332          2 hrs 15 mins    M,F,Su           17/11/17         18/12/17

ME 304         0       BEY 8:30          CAI 10:00         320          1 hr 30 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 404         0       BEY 8:40          KWI 11:55         320          2 hrs 15 mins    M,T,W,Th,F,Su    05/11/17         01/01/18

ME 364         0       BEY 8:55          JED 12:25         320          2 hrs 30 mins    M,T,F,Sa,Su      05/11/17         17/12/17

ST 3049        0       BEY 9:55          DUS 13:35         73G          4 hrs 40 mins    F                05/11/17         23/03/18

MS 710         0       BEY 10:20         CAI 11:45         738          1 hr 25 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

IA 132         0       BEY 11:00         BGW 13:30         767          1 hr 30 mins     F                17/11/17         18/11/18

G9 386         0       BEY 11:25         SHJ 17:00         320          3 hrs 35 mins    M,T,W,F          05/11/17         06/12/17

FZ 158         0       BEY 11:25         DXB 17:15         73H          3 hrs 50 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

IA 3368        0       BEY 11:30         NJF 14:00         321          1 hr 30 mins     F                17/11/17         18/11/18

ST 6003        0       BEY 11:50         SXF 15:05         73G          4 hrs 15 mins    F                05/11/17         23/03/18

IA 3358        0       BEY 12:00         NJF 14:30         330          1 hr 30 mins     F                17/11/17         18/11/18

EK 958         0       BEY 12:05         DXB 17:30         77W          3 hrs 25 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 322         0       BEY 12:20         BGW 14:50         320          1 hr 30 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

KU 502         0       BEY 12:20         KWI 15:25         332          2 hrs 5 mins     F,Su             05/11/17         18/11/18

ME 4434        0       BEY 12:35         DOH 17:45         788          4 hrs 10 mins    F,Sa,Su          01/12/17         03/12/17

QR 417         0       BEY 12:35         DOH 17:45         788          4 hrs 10 mins    T,F,Sa,Su        01/12/17         05/12/17

GF 910         0       BEY 13:00         BAH 17:10         320          3 hrs 10 mins    M,T,W,F,Su       05/11/17         18/11/18

TO 3331        0       BEY 13:00         ORY 16:45         73H          4 hrs 45 mins    M,W,F            05/11/17         23/03/18

RJ 404         0       BEY 13:10         AMM 15:00         E75          1 hr 50 mins     F                17/11/17         08/12/17

ME 314         0       BEY 13:15         AMM 14:25         320          1 hr 10 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

RJ (ME) 3755   0       BEY 13:15         AMM 14:25         320          1 hr 10 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

EY 538         0       BEY 13:20         AUH 19:15         789          3 hrs 55 mins    M,T,Th,F,Sa,Su   30/11/17         24/03/18

ME 4414        0       BEY 13:20         AUH 19:15         789          3 hrs 55 mins    M,T,Th,F,Sa,Su   30/11/17         24/03/18

ME 5504        0       BEY 13:35         TUN 16:10         320          3 hrs 35 mins    F,Su             05/11/17         23/03/18

TU 848         0       BEY 13:35         TUN 16:10         320          3 hrs 35 mins    F,Su             17/11/17         23/03/18

SV 642         0       BEY 14:00         JED 18:00         330          3 hrs 0 mins     M,Th,F,Sa,Su     01/12/17         24/03/18

ME 324         0       BEY 14:05         EBL 17:05         320          2 hrs 0 mins     Daily            14/11/17         05/12/17

ME 436         0       BEY 14:35         DOH 18:15         320          2 hrs 40 mins    T,W,Th,F,Sa,Su   30/11/17         06/12/17

QR (ME) 4901   0       BEY 14:35         DOH 18:15         320          2 hrs 40 mins    T,W,Th,F,Sa,Su   30/11/17         06/12/17

KK 1343        0       BEY 15:15         ADA 17:30         321          1 hr 15 mins     Th,F             05/11/17         23/03/18

UKM 4202       0       BEY 15:15         HRK 18:45         735          3 hrs 30 mins    F                05/11/17         18/11/18

EY (ME) 7853   0       BEY 15:25         AUH 20:30         320          3 hrs 5 mins     M,T,W,Th,F,Sa    30/11/17         09/12/17

ME 418         0       BEY 15:25         AUH 20:30         320          3 hrs 5 mins     M,T,W,Th,F,Sa    30/11/17         09/12/17

ME 2825        0       BEY 15:45         IST 18:55         333          2 hrs 10 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

TK 825         0       BEY 15:45         IST 18:55         333          2 hrs 10 mins    Daily            23/11/17         24/03/18

AF 565         0       BEY 15:55         CDG 19:35         77W          4 hrs 40 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 205         0       BEY 15:55         CDG 19:35         77W          4 hrs 40 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

SV 644         0       BEY 16:00         RUH 20:30         320          3 hrs 30 mins    T,F,Su           01/12/17         12/12/17

FZ 5156        0       BEY 16:00         DWC 21:40         73H          3 hrs 40 mins    M,W,F            15/11/17         15/12/17

ME 428         0       BEY 16:15         DXB 21:25         320          3 hrs 10 mins    M,F              24/11/17         01/12/17

AZ 825         0       BEY 16:35         FCO 19:10         32S          3 hrs 35 mins    M,F,Sa,Su        05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 2231        0       BEY 16:35         FCO 19:10         32S          3 hrs 35 mins    M,F,Sa,Su        05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 312         0       BEY 16:50         AMM 18:00         320          1 hr 10 mins     M,W,F,Sa         05/11/17         24/03/18

RJ (ME) 3753   0       BEY 16:50         AMM 18:00         320          1 hr 10 mins     Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

IA 3364        0       BEY 17:30         NJF 20:00         321          1 hr 30 mins     F                17/11/17         18/11/18

ME 267         0       BEY 17:35         IST 20:30         332          1 hr 55 mins     M,T,W,F,Sa       01/12/17         09/12/17

TK (ME) 8167   0       BEY 17:35         IST 20:30         332          1 hr 55 mins     M,T,W,F,Sa       01/12/17         09/12/17

ME 442         0       BEY 17:35         DMM 21:00         320          2 hrs 25 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

SV (ME) 6036   0       BEY 17:35         DMM 21:00         320          2 hrs 25 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

ME 203         0       BEY 17:35         LHR 20:50         320          5 hrs 15 mins    Daily            05/11/17         14/12/17

ME 306         0       BEY 17:45         CAI 19:15         320          1 hr 30 mins     Daily            05/11/17         04/12/17

ME 368         0       BEY 17:45         JED 21:15         320          2 hrs 30 mins    M,T,W,Th,F,Su    01/12/17         12/12/17

ME 422         0       BEY 17:55         RUH 21:10         320          2 hrs 15 mins    T,F              24/11/17         01/12/17

IA 140         0       BEY 18:00         NJF 20:30         737          1 hr 30 mins     M,T,Th,F,Sa      05/11/17         18/11/18

IA 3360        0       BEY 18:00         NJF 20:30         330          1 hr 30 mins     F                17/11/17         18/11/18

ME 402         0       BEY 18:05         KWI 21:20         320          2 hrs 15 mins    Daily            05/11/17         24/03/18

MS 712         0       BEY 19:10         CAI 20:35         738          1 hr 25 mins     Daily            22/11/17         24/12/17

EK 954         0       BEY 19:25         DXB 1:15 +1       77W          3 hrs 50 mins    Daily            23/11/17         11/12/17

ME 4438        0       BEY 19:25         DOH 0:35 +1       77W          4 hrs 10 mins    F                01/12/17         08/12/17

QR 421         0       BEY 19:25         DOH 0:35 +1       359          4 hrs 10 mins    Daily            01/12/17         11/12/17

ME 261         0       BEY 20:00         LCA 20:45         320           45 mins         M,W,Th,F,Sa      23/11/17         02/12/17

J9 267         0       BEY 20:35         KWI 0:30 +1       320          2 hrs 55 mins    W,Th,F,Sa,Su     05/11/17         03/12/17

ME 430         0       BEY 20:55         DXB 2:05 +1       320          3 hrs 10 mins    F                05/11/17         23/03/18

ME 3314        0       BEY 21:20         AMM 23:10         E75          1 hr 50 mins     M,T,W,F,Su       27/11/17         05/12/17

RJ 406         0       BEY 21:20         AMM 23:10         E75          1 hr 50 mins     M,T,Th,F,Sa      30/11/17         12/12/17

KU 504         0       BEY 21:40         KWI 0:45 +1       332          2 hrs 5 mins     W,F,Sa           05/11/17         18/11/18

CO 443         0       BEY 23:15         LCA 23:59         320           44 mins         W,F,Su           24/11/17         03/12/17

IA 3362        0       BEY 23:55         BGW 2:30 +1       330          1 hr 35 mins     F                17/11/17         18/11/18

ME 571         1       BEY 2:05          ABJ 9:15          332          9 hrs 10 mins    T,F              05/11/17         05/01/18
```

If you want to keep up to date with routes at a particular airport, I find [www.routesonline.com](https://www.routesonline.com/news/tagged/1942/routes-update/) is quite good.

Comment: Sorry for missing to make clear I was looking for flights with available seats. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you look at that specific airport's website? They have a full list of departing and arriving airlines. You can search day/date wise and also establish a trend, if that's what you are looking to do

Comment: Airport websites typically list only same-day departures or provide a season flight plan. Season plans list a hundred of flights and give you rules for weekdays, with the footnote that they schedule may vary though. Hard to process that information.